# Bug in PHP json_decode() when passing a json file

Tags: php, json

Consider  `j.json` file that its content is following valid json:

```
{
    "t": "\\"
}
```

PHP json_encode can not pars it:

```
$r=json_decode(file_get_contents('j.json'));

var_dump($r); //returns null
```

**note:** The question is cleaned up, the problem is same.

Comment: SO, what is in your your `j.json` ? You edited it, and now it doesn't look like valid `JSON` to me. Did you do this with some reason? Because now the question (and the answers) do not make much sense anymore....

Comment: Ok, but the problem is still the same, as you just made it simpler? That's a good thing, but it does make below answers a bit... hard to read, maybe you could've just added a tiny bit of explanation that this is a simplified version of your other code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately  `json_decode` is implemented incorrectly and may return null when get some valid json **file** or may modify their values, you can use following function that can decode all valid json strings:

```
function r_json_decode($jsonString,$originalJsonValue=false){

    $j=($originalJsonValue)?str_replace('\\','\\\\\\\\',$jsonString):str_replace('\\','\\\\',$jsonString);
    return json_decode($j);

}


echo(r_json_decode(file_get_contents('j.json'))->t);     // prints "/"
echo(r_json_decode(file_get_contents('j.json'),true)->t); //prints "//"
```

Answer (score 6):

You need this:

```
<?php
json_decode('{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\\\\.sudoc\\\\.abes\\\\.fr"
}')
```

You escaped the `\\`s only one time. You need two times, the first time is for PHP, and the second time is for JSON.

**P.S. Since your string in the JSON looks like an RegExp, you may need to do one more time escaping, i.e. double the number of backslashes again**

---

Let me try to visualize what's going on. First in PHP, you write the string in this way:

```
$s='{"a":"^http://(www|corail)\\\\\\\\.sudoc\\\\\\\\.abes\\\\\\\\.fr"}'
```

After this, if you `echo $s` you will find this:

```
{"a":"^http://(www|corail)\\\\.sudoc\\\\.abes\\\\.fr"}
```

Then if you `json_decode($s)`, the member `a` will have the content:

```
^http://(www|corail)\\.sudoc\\.abes\\.fr
```

Finally when you perform the RegExp, `\\` is further escaped into `\`.

---

If you try:

```
<?php
echo '{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\\.sudoc\\.abes\\.fr"
}';
```

the output is:

```
{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\.sudoc\.abes\.fr"
}
```

See what's wrong? In JSON (JavaScript) `\.` is **not** a valid escape sequence, and so it **is not a valid JSON**, and so `json_decode` will fail, returning `NULL`.

---

If you try:

```
<?php
echo '{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\\\\.sudoc\\\\.abes\\\\.fr"
}';
```

the output is:

```
{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\\.sudoc\\.abes\\.fr"
}
```

which the escape sequence `\\` will be valid for JSON.

Comment: @Reza **Because you need to escape all slashes.** Can't you read my answer?

Comment: Actually, because [`NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @AlvinWong I would also explain that slashes are used to escape a PHP string, hence why a double slash in a PHP literal string results in one actual slash in that string.

Comment: @Christian I see that the OP escaped `\ ` one time, so I think he knew about escaping... But a bit more seeing **the string is in fact an RegEx** so it may need one more time of escaping.

Comment: Also, I think using var_export is a good pointer. Since no one wants to upvote my answer, I think it's worth mentioning this fact in yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
json_decode('{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\\\\.sudoc\\\\.abes\\\\.fr"
}');
```

You had an extra comma, and you have to escape the backslashes twice (first for the php string, and then for the json).

```
echo "\\"; // outputs "\"
echo "\\\\"; // outputs "\\", ie what you need for the json
```

Comment: **-1** It's not just about commas. I don't even know why you got up-voted....it doesn't [even work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Yu65PH).

Comment: You're right, i missed the backslashes thing. Edited with a short and simple explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

echo var_export(json_encode((object)array('target'=>'^http://(www|corail)\\.sudoc\\.abes\\.fr')));

echo '<br/>';

echo '{
    "target": "^http://(www|corail)\\.sudoc\\.abes\\.fr"
}';
```

**What I did here is that I wrote the object manually in PHP, encoded it into JSON then ["exported"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) it to see it as a PHP string.**

Then I compared it with your string.

Here's the result:

```
'{"target":"^http:\\/\\/(www|corail)\\\\.sudoc\\\\.abes\\\\.fr"}'
{ "target": "^http://(www|corail)\.sudoc\.abes\.fr" }
```

You can clearly see that your string missed some characters: you need to escape all forward and backward slashes.

Comment: didn't realize that `/` also needs to be escaped into `\/`, or is that in fact optional?

Comment: @AlvinWong It is indeed optional. I would have thought it's there for a reason, but try as I might, I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is obivously about escaping. There seems to be some discussion about how JSON is parsed in in PHP (see the comments over at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php ).

Anyway, as you can see from this "fiddle" http://codepad.viper-7.com/2t4pP0 you need to start adding them backslashes!
It does this:

```
<?php
    $r=json_decode('{"t": "a"}');
    var_dump($r);
echo "<br/>\n";
    $r=json_decode('{"t": "\a"}');
    var_dump($r);
echo "<br/>\n";
    $r=json_decode('{"t": "\\a"}');
    var_dump($r);
echo "<br/>\n";
    $r=json_decode('{"t": "\\\a"}');
    var_dump($r);
echo "<br/>\n";
    $r=json_decode('{"t": "\\\\a"}');
    var_dump($r);
```

and outputs

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["t"]=> string(1) "a" } 
NULL 
NULL 
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["t"]=> string(2) "\a" } 
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["t"]=> string(2) "\a" }
```

Now depending on what you are trying to accomplish (in the current edit of your question there is no goal mentioned), you should be able to figure out what to do with this?